# Nexus 6P GPS location inaccuracies

Tags: gps, google-maps, geolocation, nexus-6p

I have a brand-new Nexus 6P, not rooted, running Android 6.0.1. I have location mode set to high accuracy (with GPS, WiFi Scanning, and Bluetooth Scanning all set to on). Almost all of the time, this works well: location detection is fairly accurate, and while navigating with Google Maps, the GPS has worked as it should.

However, once in a while (every day or so) when I am at home (and have been for at least 3-4 hours), my Nexus thinks I am at work. Not just one app: my IFTTT recipes set to go off when I reach work activate, Life360 (the family location tracking app) alerts my family that I've arrived at work, Google Now offers me the commute time to my home, and Google Maps shows my current location as work. A minute or two later, the issue dissolves and my phone thinks I'm at home once again. **Note:** my work is almost a mile away from my home, so it's not a minor gps error.

In a couple days of testing, the issue has not occurred when my location mode is set to "Battery Saver," which doesn't use GPS but rather approximates location with Cellular, Wifi, and Bluetooth. So, I think this is a GPS issue with my phone. Battery Saver location mode, however, makes navigating with Google Maps difficult (the bubble of where I might be is a little on the large side), and Google Maps constantly prompts me to re-enable GPS and high accuracy mode.

What should I do to fix this issue and what could be an explanation for this?

Comment: I don't have any issues with GPS on the Nexus 6P.

Comment: It's not plausible that a problem with a GPS receiver would make your location jump directly from work to home. It's a lot more likely to be caused by one of those other sources, which is just operating differently in Battery Saver mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I left my GPS on Battery Saver mode for a while (maybe a week or two) then turned it back on to High Accuracy afterwards; the problem went away.